# How to print the result of a variable in echo in bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script, I would like to print `now` inside the echo, I receive an error and not able to make it. Could you please point me out in the right direction?

```
    $now = date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
    echo '
    {
        "a": {
            "timestamp": $now,
        },
    }
    '
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Don't use single quote in `echo` to expand variables

Comment: could you please post a working solution, I would be glad to accept an answer :)

Comment: Assignment should be without the dollar sign and without spaces around the equal sign. You should use Command Substitution to capture the output of the `date` command.

Comment: That's barely even *close* to valid `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your syntax of creating variable `now` is wrong it should be:

```
now=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Then instead of using `echo` you should use `cat` that supports `here-doc` like this:

```
cat<<-EOF
{
     "a": {
         "timestamp": $now,
     },
}
EOF
```

This way you don't need to worry about handling quotes and escaping double quotes inside double quotes. [Remember that your single quotes in `echo` don't expand shell variables.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `"` double quotes to expand shell variables.

Consider:

```
$ i=22
$ echo "i=$i"
i=22
$ echo 'i=$i'
i=$i
```

Since you have literal double quotes you want in your interpolated string, you need to backslash escape them:

```
now=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
echo "{
    \"a\": {
         \"timestamp\": $now,
     },
 }"
```

Prints:

```
{
   "a": {
        "timestamp": 2019-10-22T15:52:41Z,
    },
}
```